# Oracle SDO_GEOM.SDO_MBR Wrong Bounding Box Coordinates

Tags: oracle-spatial

I am using Oracle Spatial to match geo-specific images to the appropriate country they represent.

I have a table with a row for each country. Each row consists of a SDO_GEOMETRY column for 3 items: SHAPE (overall boundaries), CENTROID (centerpoint of the country) and MBR (Minimum Bounding Rectangle). The Centroid and MBR fields are auto-computed using SDO_GEOM.CENTROID and SDO_GOEM.SDO_MBR respectively.

Mostly there are no issues, however... For some countries that span the 180deg Longitude line, the MBR created is wrong. I believe this is caused by Oracle handling the (co)Ordinates as X,Y values.

For instance, using Russia as an example. The LowerLeft value of the MBR is returned as (41.19268056, -180) while the UpperRight value is returned as (81.858710028, 180). When mapping this bounding box, it covers a swatch that spans 360deg (and encompasses many countries along the way).

Another example is Kiribati. The LL returned is (-11.46111418, -174.543405728) and the UR is (4.7230899, 176.850922). Mapping this shows the bounding box as NOT crossing the 180Lat line, but rather spanning -174 to +176, when it should be progressing from 176...178...180...-178...-176...-174.

Any thoughts or ideas as to an solution?

===========================

## EDIT

SQL used to populate the MBR row:

```
UPDATE schema.table SET mbr=sdo_geom.sdo_mbr(geometry);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the SQL you are using to populate the row.

Comment: What application are you using to map this?  I seem to remember something about not using MBRs for this sort of purpose.  They were only supposed to be used for querying data.  I can't find the reference to it in the documentation though.  Have you tried using a normal polygon (with 5 points)?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: @travis: I am using ArcMap to double-check the results.